# Active Directory: Do I need to register both native app and web app in azure or can I use 1 registered app for both?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am building an app that will have Native iOS, Android apps + a web app version. These will be the same thing, working with the same backend and the same data, they will have to share the roles and other app-related data so I don't think it will just 'work' to register it as native-app for the native apps and as a web-app for the web app as then I'll ahve 2 different applications with different ids and different roles.

What are we supposed to do in this situation?

- Register an app for each platform anyway
- Register just the web version and use it for both? or the Native one?
- Is there some type of configuration to get this working in Azure that I'm missing out?

Comment: I think you can register one app for the whole thing, that was one of the things made possible in the new app model. I'd probably still register one app for each platform + one for the API.

Comment: But then wouldn't you have issues with roles consistency across paltform since those are stored as part of the app registration? You then must add/remove roles on both platforms all the time?

Comment: Well you can't use roles in native apps anyway, best place to define the roles might be the API app registration. If you want to know user roles in front-end, you can decode the token and check from there. Your API should implement the access controls related to roles.

Comment: @juunas I think my question was unclear -- I don't mean what the user can/can't do in the app or what request to make. Strictly storing role information in the authentication token. I've done this for web apps in the past, I know you implement your own logic and only read the role from the token. But if the token comes from a different app on native and another in web, won't you need to maintain consistency between the two for that user?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean. An access token acquired for a user from Azure AD will always have the same format, only some values will be different, like the calling app's id. Okay, maybe the permissions granted on the client app can be different, which you would need to keep in sync, is that what you meant?

Comment: @juunas yes -- but it seems that if you register an app through the new interface at http://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ you can add both platforms and redirect URI's to the same app. It seems to be marked as in 'preview' in Azure but otherwise works.

I've been having a ton of issues with Oauth2 in my nativescript app which I've posted about on two different threads and I thought some of those issues are because of the type of app I've registered but after trying more things I think it has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We encourage you use the same app registration for apps that are essentially the same but built for different platforms

The new "App registrations (Preview)" enables you to do that.

By reading more from the comments, emphasizing on the "same app" bit. Microsoft word is the same app, whether its the web version or the client versions of it on Windows, IOS and Android.

But if you have apps that are functionally different, then you should consider registering them separately. For example, front end client app and back-end WebAPI should be different app registrations

Comment: that's exactly what I ended up doing -- registering an app through the new portal and using that client ID, added the platforms manually and all is well in the world, thanks!